# Broken FindBugs in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Using Eclipse STS 2.9.1, I cannot make  FindBugs 2 working. 
When I right click on the project and "FindBugs", I got an error stating that my project is missing org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator.

Does anyone encountered the same issue and managed to solve it?

Comment: My initial guess is that find bugs is not correctly installed, but I can't say for certain w/o seeing the full error log entry.  Go to Window -> Show view -> Other -> Error log.  Paste the relevant entry above.

Comment: I uninstalled it, restarted eclipse, re-installed, restarted eclipse : same result. As for the error message, I got nothing more than the missing BundleActivator package.

Comment: Where does the error appear? Is it in the problems view?  Or in the error log?  If in the problems view, what resource is marked with this problem?

Comment: It appears in the error log when I click "Find bugs" on the projet.
I tested it with another version of Eclipse : Helios 3.6.1 and it works. So my question becomes : does anybody here managed to install findbug with sts 2.9.1 and made it work on JVM 1.6.30 64Bits ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Find bugs works for me on STS 3.0.0.M1.

I also meant to ask you for the full stack trace in your error log.  You can paste that in your answer.

But, probably your best bet will be to uninstall and reinstall the feature.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
It's now worse : I do not even have an error in the error log, the progress bar grows up to 100%, then nothing, it simply disappears.
I already tried the uninstall, but since I got some time to lose, I will continue to investigate. After all, there's no magic here :)

Comment: Installed a new STS 2.9.1 and findbug 2. No error log when I click find bugs on my project. but finds no bugs (I know I'm good but not to that point ;) )